# iPhone networking game

Tags: iphone, networking

I already know how to make a online game using wi-Fi and bluetooth, but now i'm trying to implement a simple game over the internet(like a tic-tac-toe), but i'm kind lost.

I tried GET/POST, but i have no idea in how to notify a player that's waiting to move, and how to preserve the game state.

Do i have to open a socket on the server side, and connect from within the app?
I already made a extensive search, but i can only find about bluetooth and wifi, and that's not what i need.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this library: http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

For the server side, you could use something like node.js or Python Twisted to open socket connections.

Sample code from one of my own projects. This sets up a socket that just reads from the host every 10 seconds. Your game will be a little different:

```
- (void) createSocket { 
  aisSocket = [[AsyncSocket alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
  NSError *error;
  [aisSocket connectToHost:myServerString 
                    onPort:myServerPort 
                     error:&error];
}


- (BOOL)onSocketWillConnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock {
  NSLog(@"socket will connect");
  return YES;
}


- (void) readData:(NSNotification*)note {
  [[note.userInfo objectForKey:@"sock"] readDataWithTimeout:100 tag:0];
}   


- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port {
  NSLog(@"The socket is connected: %d", [aisSocket isConnected]);
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sock forKey:@"sock"];
  NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(10)
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(readData:)
                                                   userInfo:dict
                                                    repeats:YES]retain];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Comment: Thanks you guys for the answers. I have downloaded asynchSock, and now i'm able to connect with the server. I have a php script that creates the server socket for me. My doubt now is how to setup the game architeture...how do i synchronize the users/game play? Thanks again!

Comment: I think this tutorial will help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12

Comment: You also might want the book listed in this forum - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12893

Answer (score 0):

Go read Apple's [WiTap Sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html), it should match what you are trying to do.

Also consult [GameKit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to know how to make multiple devices discover themselves then communicate with each other in a game (or anything else)

Comment: I already know how to do Wi-fi and bounjour stuff. The problem is which tools to use related to the server...also, i don't know if a have to put the game logic on the server, or use the server only to send my packets to the other connected devices...